# Draw a circle with four segments

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, this question was posted for Androids, but I couldn't find anything relating to HTML/CSS/Javascript. How can I draw a circle with four different segments to interact with?

The level of interaction I'm looking for is simple enough - just something to accept hover and click commands. I've done a lot of looking and I can't come up with anything. I know how to create a circle, but not one with four different areas I can interact with. Can anyone help?

Comment: Add images to explain what you mean, the words are not enough to understand what you're talking about. Or, ever better, images, and a jsbin/jsfiddle/etc to show code you've already tried, to see what you're thinking of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html:

```
<a id="s1"></a>
<a id="s2"></a>
<a id="s3"></a>
<a id="s4"></a>
```

css:

```
a{
display:inline-block;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:green;
}
a:hover{
background:blue;
}
#s1{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
border-top-left-radius:50px;
}
#s2{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:50px;
border-top-right-radius:50px;
}
#s3{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:0px;
border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
}
#s4{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:50px;
border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/efLc2jww/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/cardeo/8ku6T/)** , the concept is pretty easy.

```
.quarter-circle {
    background-color:#c06;
    height:150px;
    width: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
}
```

just stick 4 quarters in 1 wrap div like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/8ku6T/386/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
<p class="quarter-circle"></p>
<p class="quarter-circle fliph"></p>
<p class="quarter-circle flipv"></p>
<p class="quarter-circle fliphv"></p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrap
{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;

}
.fliph
{
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
.flipv
{
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
        transform: scaleY(-1);
        filter: FlipV;
        -ms-filter: "FlipV";
}
.fliphv
{
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
        transform: scaleY(-1) scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipV;
        -ms-filter: "FlipV";
}
.quarter-circle {
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#c06;
    height:150px;
    width: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.c {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}
.c:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.tl {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}
.tr {
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
.bl {
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
.br {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="c tl"></div><div class="c tr"></div><div class="c bl"></div><div class="c br"></div>
```